# Share docker images between hosts with NFS

Tags: docker, nfs, mesos, device-mapper

I'building a mesosphere infrastructure on AWS instances with 3 master servers (running zookeeper, mesos-master, marathon and haproxy) and N slaves (running mesos-slave and docker).

If I run the same container on different slaves marathon downloads on each slave the same image. I would like to share one single nfs export (say on master1) and mount it on every slave in order to have a unique storage for the images.

Im using Ubuntu on the EC2 instances, so the storage driver used by default is device-mapper. I set up the slaves to mount /var/lib/docker/devicemapper and /var/lib/docker/graph but it ends up with this error: "stale NFS file handle"

What I would like to understand is:

- There is a way to do it using a different storage driver?
- In any case is the docker daemon doing some look on the files in this directory?
- Is my approach wrong or possible leading into "cconcurrency access issues?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using NFS to expose the backing file system, I think it would be easier to set up docker-registry (with a volume on the master1, so the data is persisted there) and on the other nodes pull images via docker protocol by e.g. `docker pull master1:5000/image:latest`